# How to design html pages which renders properly in windows while staying in Linux?

Tags: html, css, django, xhtml, django-templates

I usually prefer linux for programming( i program in django on Ubuntu).
But often i need to design html pages which renders properly in Windows and Linux?

How iam currently doing the above is

1. Design (Fix) html page in linux
2. Reboot to windows check whether the
   design is proper or not.    if not
   reboot to linux
         repeat step1 ,step2

i felt the above process is tedious.
Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a virtual machine to host your Windows installation, if you have a Windows license (which I'm guessing you do by the fact you reboot into Windows), and the RAM to keep a virtualized instance of XP or whatever Windows you use to test.

Using VMWare or VirtualBox you could set up a shared folder so both the virtual instance and Linux can look at the same file to test the website locally.

Comment: Xen or QEmu may get you started a little smoother on linux than VMWare or VirtualBox, but all four should be able to get the work done.

Answer (score 5):

There is a great free service called [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) that you can provide a link to which will take screenshots of a site in multiple browsers and OS's. It supports the Linux, Windows, OS X and BSD operating systems, and a large number of major and minor browser (including several versions of each).

There's also [IEs4Linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page) which will use Wine to install Internet Explorer within Linux. This solution isn't perfect though, as the rendering isn't exact and it can be difficult to install (and get working) any plugins beyond flash. Also, IE 7 & 8 aren't officially supported yet.

Other Options:

- For environments with multiple devs, create one server with several virtualized windows installs with different versions. Devs can use remote desktop to test sites on the local network.
- If you have a 2nd machine handy, install windows on it and a kvm switch to test on this system.

Answer (score 1):

If a website is being correctly displayed doesn't depend much on the operating system. It mainly depends on the webbrowser and its engine.

A webpage being rendered in FF 3.0 on Linux will look exactly as on a windows machine.

Some suggestions if your browser doesn't support Linux by default:

- Use a virtual machine (such as VirtualBox)
- Install desired browser in Wine
- You can use online renderers such as: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/

Comment: it also depends on operating system.In ubuntu the rendering of a web page is slightly different from rendering of web page in windows.

Comment: These online renderer's can't render local files.We need to move the files to  some hosting servers in order to see via BroswerShots, netrenderer

Comment: Rendering on different OS's is NOT the same.  SO has looked like garbage on certain flavors of linux for while, using the same version FF.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what people have said about Virtual Machines, you need to know how to make your django test server available to them. To do this, I use:

> python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.xx:80

where xx is your local IP address. Then you can browse the site as you're making it, both from virtual boxes running on your Linux host and from other machines on your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Use as many browser platforms for testing as you can under Linux: Firefox, Opera, Konqueror. If you pages work in these browsers, test in IE using BrowserShots or Wine.

Comment: The problem is when you have to test JS too. Furthermore, if it works under FF, Opera and Konqueror, it's likely it will work with anything you throw at it AS LONG AS IT IS NOT IE. IE gives you NO guaranties.

Answer (score 0):

as Adviced by many people here:

i advice using virtual machines, if you have a server at hand or even better multiple servers you could try and install vmware server version 2.0 so that you and other people can use the same (virtual) machine for testing.

also it is true that most of the free browsers look the same on diferend Operating systems but bare in mind that some operating systems are lacking fonts you might want, this will make a huge diference.

with that in mind i advice go virtual an go for a good and free selution vmware server